# Удалить одинаковые элементы массива - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Не удаляются одинаковые элементы двумерного массива [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я это делаю так:

```
    type 
      TaXiz = array [0..1,0..1000] of real; 
    type 
      TaXYiz = array [0..1000,0..1] of real;

    var
      i,v,b,z: Integer;
      aXYiz,aXYizu: TaXYiz;
    ...

  v:=Length(aXYiz)-1;
  i:=0;
  while i<=v do
   begin
    b:=i+1;
    while b<=v do
     begin
      if (aXYiz[b,0]=aXYiz[i,0]) and (aXYiz[b,1]=aXYiz[i,1]) then
      begin
        for z:=b to v-1 do
        begin
          aXYiz[z]:=aXYiz[z+1];
          v:=v-1;
        end;
      end
       else b:=b+1;
     end;
   end;
```

Comment: "Не удаляются" - а что? Вы бы хоть декларацию типа `TaXYiz` показали. Вы отладчиком проходили по коду? И как? Что, на Ваш взгляд, делает вот эта проверка `aXYiz[b]=aXYiz[i]`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не должен был задавать несколько вопросов в одном комментарии. Современные молодые люди не способны думать две мысли одновременно.

Comment: Мне всё равно, сколько вопросов в одном   комментарии. Я просто отвлёкся и отходил   type TaXiz = array [0..1,0..1000] of real;
  type TaXYiz = array [0..1000,0..1] of real;

Comment: aXYiz[b][0]=aXYiz[i][0] эта проверка сравнивает, два значения в массиве.   b:=i+1; - следующий элемент . i- элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое. У Вас неправильная индексация массива - должна быть от нуля до (длина - 1).

Второе. Логика внутри внутреннего `while` от меня ускользает. Напишите ее словами, потом возьмите листок бумаги и на достаточно простом примере выполните все действия. Убедитесь, что результат соответствует Вашим ожиданиям.

Третье. Не пренебрегайте ключевыми словами `begin/end` - в цикле `for z:=b to v-1 do` их явно не хватает.

И четвертое. Термин "удаление" слабо применим к статическому массиву - но это может объясняться логикой кода, не вошедшего в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас работаю над устранением ошибок логических и семантических) и Я этот пример нашёл, сейчас пытаюсь его сделать рабочим